# correct way to retrieve mysql data on heavy load

Tags: php, mysql

I have build a system using PHP-MySQL. This system is subject to a very heavy load, with thousands of selects,updates,inserts,deletes every minute.

I would like to optimize this system, to make it faster, and reduce load on the servers.
I have already introduced memcache, but mysql data is still needed.

So my question is, which method would be the best in this case.
Currently my queries would look like this:

```
$q = mysql_query($sql);
while(mysql_fetch_array($q)) {...
```

I have read that there is a little speed to gain by using mysql_fetch_assoc (?)

But perhaps there is an antirely different approach, when i start optimizing this system?

Thank you all - (Apologies for my limited english skills)

Comment: I would look into mysql server replication. Mysql_ functions shouldn't be used anymore at all.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: **Limit** the results, as user clicks **more results**, load **more results**..

Comment: the amount of cpu time spent on fetch_assoc v.s. fetch_array is going to be minuscule compared to anything you do to optimize the query itself and tuning your DB server.

Comment: By the time `mysql_query` has returned, the mysql server has already completed its work.  Switching to `mysql_fetch_assoc` would do nothing to reduce database server load.  As to how to speed things up: [you can always cache more](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3112-how-basecamp-next-got-to-be-so-damn-fast-without-using-much-client-side-ui).  A write-through cache should help you get up-to-date data without hitting the db.

Comment: Generate a slow query report, and fix your slow queries (by using more efficient queries, adding indexes, caching, etc.)

Comment: Pagination, narrow the queries to return only what needed in that moment. Also limit the columns selected, make index the columns commonly used for search, and of course, cache, cache, cache...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_assoc` vs `mysql_fetch_array` will duplicate less data thus use less memory. Since the data is presented associative and by `index` in the array, with that you will get some tiny optimization although will help if your dataset is big.

- Try to use `natural` sort (AKA avoid SORT in query sentences) and `LIMIT` your result set if you can
- Batch queries: instead run 100 inserts over the same table try to do a few of them small.
- cache cache cache if you can: using redis or memcached.
- if you generate pages that can be treated as static try to use HTTP headers to avoid browsers to request your site all the time
- etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use the mysql keyword LIMIT to limit the result set.

Adding pagination to the mysql returning resultset will make your application lighter, the ui will load faster because of less rows to fetch and the mysql server will only receive the select queries when needed.
Basically this is the syntax of how to use limit.

SELECT * FROM Person LIMIT X,Y

Where X is the total row count to be retrieved and Y the offset.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Person LIMIT 10, 0
```

This query will return the first ten rows of the table Person, and:

```
SELECT * FROM Person LIMIT 10, 10
```

Will display the next 10

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing some timing tests on various methods of getting information out of MySQL in PHP. The goal was to find the fastest way of transferring a column of data into a simple array. I've tested it against the enSEMBL database, which is usefully huge.

The following code was common for methods 1 to 8 (9 used GROUP_CONCAT & 10 used PDO):

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT `name` FROM species LIMIT 5000";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
*Method code*
print_r(array_filter($species));
```

Method 1: Textbook method

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
         $species[] = $row[0];
      }
```

Method 2: while and reset (NB some IDEs detect an error here)

```
while ($species[] = reset($result->fetch_row())) ;
```

Method 3: foreach and reset

```
foreach ($result->fetch_all() as $value) $species[] = reset($value);
```

Method 4: while, foreach and reset

```
while ($species[] = $result->fetch_row()) ;
foreach ($species as $key => $value) $species[$key] = reset($value);
```

Method 5: while and index

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) $species[] = $row[0];
```

Method 6: foreach and index

```
foreach ($result->fetch_all() as $value) $species[] = $value[0];
```

Method 7: recurse the array

```
$species = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $result->fetch_all());
```

Method 8: array_column

```
$species = array_column($result->fetch_all(), 0);
```

Method 9: Using GROUP_CONCAT in query.

```
$species = explode(',', $result->fetch_row()[0]);
```

Method 10: PDO

```
$species = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

Surprisingly Method 1 (Textbook) was consistently about 4 times longer than the practically identical Method 5, but took about the same time as Method 10 (PDO).

Method 2 was consistently the slowest method at 50x longer, presumably because the system is writing warnings somewhere.

Method 4 (two loops) was the second slowest, taking 10x longer.

As stated Methods 1(textbook) & 10 (PDO) were third.

Method 9 was fourth slowest (2x longer, and had the disadvantage of hitting the GROUP_CONCAT limit without any warning).

The fastest method, however, wasn't consistent. Take your pick from 3, 5, 6, 7 & 8.

Method 8 (array_column) was often the fastest way to do this, but not always. However I think it's the most elegant method and provides slightly more flexibility as it can return an associative array using any two columns selected by your query (but don't mess with the order in the query!)